# HTML2PDF not handling display: none

Tags: php, html, html2pdf

I'm trying to use the [HTML2PDF](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf) PHP library to generate a PDF starting from a complex HTML page. The PDF is being generated successfully, but the HTML elements of my source page that have `style="display: none"` are being displayed in the PDF. I need the elements that have `display: none` in the HTML to also be hidden in the PDF.

For example, my HTML page contains this code:

```html
<style>
.test {
  display: none;
}
</style>
...

<div class="test">This is a test.</div>
```

I would expect the div not to be visible in the output PDF. Instead, it is visible.

I thought that maybe HTML2PDF was failing to read the CSS class, so I changed my HTML page to move the `display: none` to inline, like this:

```html
<div style="display: none;">This is a test.</div>
```

But this did not solve the problem. The div is still visible in the output PDF.

Then I thought maybe HTML2PDF couldn't read inline styles either, but when I changed the inline style to `text-decoration: underline` the text was actually underlined in the PDF! In other words, the following code is rendered in the output PDF as the words "This is a test" underlined:

```html
<div style="display: none; text-decoration: underline;">This is a test.</div>
```

Is it possible that the `display` CSS property is ignored by HTML2PDF? How should I change my HTML and/or CSS to successfully hide elements in the PDF?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code you are using

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to try and make it clearer. I'm writing HTML and CSS and I need HTML2PDF to understand that HTML elements with style="display: none" must not show up in the output PDF.

Comment: You haven't shared any code so far, neither PHP code nor HTML markup

Comment: I now shared my HTML. I'm not writing any PHP, the library is doing all the PHP work for me.